# SSRS Passing a GUID to a Parameter in a Sub Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've configured a line item in a report to act as a hyperlink to a sub report (Placeholder Properties > Action > Go to report).  One of the parameters that I want to pass to the sub report is a GUID.

I've configured the parameter value as follows:

`=Fields!GuidParameter.Value`

The sub report is being called and displayed but the parameter on the sub report isn't being set.  The user has to manually select the parameter value on the sub report.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of a case mismatch between the parent report (lower case GUID) and the sub report (expects upper case GUID).

I fixed it by specifiying the parameter value as:

`=UCase(CType(Fields!GuidParameter.Value, GUID).ToString())`